# How to add comma on end variable in function

Tags: php

I have problem with comma. I have a code

```
<?php echo get_the_subtitle($post); ?>, <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
```

and i need show comma ',' only when

```
<?php echo get_the_subtitle($post); ?>
```

have a subtiitle.

Example: subtitle, date. If no have a subtitle not show coma. I do something like this `<?php echo get_the_subtitle($post, ','); ?>` but comma is before subtitle not aftre ;/

Comment: Are you using a Wordpress plugin for this subtitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/benhuson/wp-subtitle/wiki/get_the_subtitle) states that the second parameter of this function is the text before and the third parameter is the text after the subtitle.

So you should do something like this:

```
<?php echo get_the_subtitle($post, '', ','); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$subtitle = get_the_subtitle($post);
echo $subtitle ? $subtitle . ', ' : '';
echo get_the_date(); 
?>
```

You need check `get_the_subtitle($post)` function returns something or not. If it returns something you should echo it with comma or it does not return something you should echo only date.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
echo (get_the_subtitle($post) != '') ? get_the_subtitle($post) .','. get_the_date() : get_the_date();
```

If the subtitle isn't blank, echo the subtitle and the date (with the comma), else just echo the date.